# how to display wordpress categories in two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, categories

I'd like to display my categories 2 at the time - 2 in each row and have as many rows as needed.

I've got so far with this code (which displays all the categories):

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0,
  'hide_empty' => 0
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );

echo count( $categories );

echo "<div class='a'>\n";
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo "<div class='b'>\n";
    echo "<div class='c'><a href='" . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . "'>" . $category->name . "</a></div>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
echo "</div>\n";
?>
```

I know it can be done using list, but this is something I want to avoid.

Comment: _I know it can be done using list, but this is something I want to avoid._ Use `<table>` and `<tr`>, is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So this is it (took a while) and it works just fine ;-)

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0,
  'hide_empty' => 1
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
$list_cats = array();
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    array_push($list_cats, $category->name);
}
$total_cats=count($categories);

echo "<div class='a'>";
for ($a=0; $a<$total_cats;) { 
   for ($j=0; $j<2; $j++) { 
            echo " <div class='b'><div class='c'>" . $list_cats[$a] . "</div></div>"; 
       $a++;
   } 
   echo "</div>"; 
   if($a<$total_cats){
            echo "<div class='a'>"; 
   }

}
```